# Rendering Array element using index in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component

I am trying to build a type of slide show of different components on the website. I have imported the required slides as individual elements and stored them in an array. I have written the basic structure but don't know how to render the component stored in the array using the index.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Slide1 from './slides/slide1.js';
import Slide2 from './slides/slide2.js';
import Slide3 from './slides/slide3.js';
import Slide4 from './slides/slide4.js';
import Slide5 from './slides/slide5.js';

function Presentation({slides,index}) {
    return(
        <div className="presentation">
            <React.Fragment key={index}> {slides[index]} </React.Fragment>  
        </div>
    )
}

function Buttons({index, setIndex, size}) {
    const nextSlide = (index) => {
        if(index<size-1) setIndex(++index)
    }
    const prevSlide = (index) => {
        if(index>0) setIndex(--index)
    }
    return(
        <nav className="buttons">
            <button onClick={(index)=>prevSlide}> Previous </button>
            <button onClick={(index)=>nextSlide}> Next </button>
        </nav>
    )
}

function Main() {
    const slides = [Slide1, Slide2, Slide3, Slide4, Slide5]
    const [index,setIndex] = useState(0);
    return(
        <main>
            <Presentation slides={slides} index={index}/>
            <Buttons index={index} setIndex={setIndex} length={slides.length}/>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

But this does not work. Does anyone have a correct or better way to do this?

Comment: You don't need a `React.Fragment`, you can simply do `<slides[index] key={index}>`.

Comment: Also, how about `<Presentation slide={slides[index]} />`? That way, you don't even need the index in the Presentation component.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I tried your first suggestion earlier, that gives an error

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: Oh you are right, try `const Slide = slides[index];`, then `<Slide key={index} />`.

Comment: That will not update the component as I want it to since the virtual dom will see no change in the Slide component... I guess... that's why I did not try that

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, React will see that the index prop changed, and it will update then. Or are you maybe talking about my second suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote some of your code since I didn't know exactly what code was behind your Slides. I defined them as  tag to be easier for me.

I changed your array and assigned JSX inside:
`const slides = [<Slide1 />, <Slide2 />];`

I remove `index` from a lot of your code in your `Button` component, since you passed it as a props.

And finally, you were passing `length` as props in your Main component to your `Button` component, but your `Button`component read from a `size` props.

Hope it will helps

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Slide1 = () => {
  return <h1>SLIDE 1</h1>;
};

const Slide2 = () => {
  return <h1>SLIDE 2</h1>;
};

function Presentation({ slides, index }) {
  const renderSlide = () => {
    return slides[index];
  };
  return <div className="presentation">{renderSlide()}</div>;
}

function Buttons({ index, setIndex, size }) {
  const nextSlide = () => {
    if (index < size - 1) setIndex(i => i + 1);
  };
  const prevSlide = () => {
    if (index > 0) setIndex(--index);
  };
  return (
    <nav className="buttons">
      <button onClick={prevSlide}> Previous </button>
      <button onClick={nextSlide}> Next </button>
    </nav>
  );
}

function Main() {
  const slides = [<Slide1 />, <Slide2 />];
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <main>
      <Presentation slides={slides} index={index} />
      <Buttons index={index} setIndex={setIndex} size={slides.length} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not calling the `prevSlide` and `nextSlide` functions, you are just returning them without passing the index.

```js
   <nav className="buttons">
      <button onClick={()=>prevSlide(index)}> Previous </button>
      <button onClick={()=>nextSlide(index)}> Next </button>
   </nav>
```

Also, I suggest to change those functions param names to other than index, since is same as the index prop of the `Buttons` component. It may lead to confusion.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. ([Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qrbcri?file=Hello.js))

Issue - 1. Buttons argument name is `size` where as passed as `length`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
const Slide1  = <div> 1 </div>;
const Slide2  = <div> 2 </div>;
const Slide3  = <div> 3 </div>;
const Slide4  = <div> 4 </div>;
const Slide5  = <div> 5 </div>;

function Presentation({slides,index}) {
    return(
        <div className="presentation">
            <React.Fragment key={index}> {slides[index]} </React.Fragment>  
        </div>
    )
}

function Buttons({index, setIndex, length}) {
    const nextSlide = () => {
      console.log('next', index, length)
       if (index < (length - 1)) {
        setIndex(index + 1)
       }
    }
    const prevSlide = () => {
       console.log('prev', index)
       if (index > 0) {
        setIndex(index - 1)
       }
    }
    return(
        <nav className="buttons">
            <button onClick={() => prevSlide()}> Previous </button>
            <button onClick={() => nextSlide()}> Next </button>
        </nav>
    )
}

function Main() {
    const slides = [Slide1, Slide2, Slide3, Slide4, Slide5]
    const [index,setIndex] = useState(0);
    return(
        <main>
            <Presentation slides={slides} index={index}/>
            <Buttons index={index} setIndex={setIndex} length={slides.length}/>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can map over the values with key and index to provide what you need

```
function Presentation({slides,index}) {

return(
    <div className="presentation">
        { slides.map((key, index) => <Slide key={key} index={index} /> }
    </div>
)
```

}

I'm just changing your <React.Fragment> to a slide component

Comment: this is not the question that I asked